# How can I addEventListener inside of a function?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm trying to addEventListener to an HTML element with id a2, inside of a function, but Chrome Dev Tools say it's an object pointer event.

I put

```
    var a2 = document.getElementById("a2");
```

inside the function and it also doesn't work.

I would appreciate any help with this problem.

```
  var a1 = document.getElementById("a1");
  a1.addEventListener("click", play);

  var a2 = document.getElementById("a2");

  function play () {
      if (this.id == a1) {
          this.removeEventListener("click", play);
          a2.addEventListener("click", play);
      }
      // do something
  };
```

Comment: What is the full error message?  What *exactly* does "it also doesn't work" mean?

Comment: `this.id == a1` is your main problem. The id will never equal an HTML element. It's also not clear why you're passing in `a2` as an argument.

Comment: this.id == a1 , works. it removes the eventlistener. It doesn't seem to make any difference if I pass in a2 or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed "a2" argument from play. Same code. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

```
  var a1 = document.getElementById("a1");
  a1.addEventListener("click", play);

  var a2 = document.getElementById("a2");

  function play() {
  
    console.log("a2")
    
    if (this.id == "a1") {
        console.log("a1")
      this.removeEventListener("click", play);
      a2.addEventListener("click", play);
    }
    // do something
  };
```

Comment: putting the a1 in quotes is what solved it. thank you very much.